# Firebase: An internal error has occurred [QUOTA_EXCEEDED]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

onComplete returns a Task with an exception saying `An internal error has occurred. [ QUOTA_EXCEEDED ]` Tried upgrading from Flame to Blaze, it worked but only for a few minutes. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(
                new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        showOverlay(false);
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            ((MenuActivity) getActivity()).showSnack(
                                    getString(R.string.fb_auth_recovery_sent),
                                    SnackView.LEVEL_POSITIVE);
                        } else {
                            showErrorSnack(task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a daily limit on sending password reset emails. Upgrading the project doesn't affect the quota for sending emails.

Comment: That really sucks. Thanks for the answer, I'll talk to Firebase about this.